# Athena query get the index of any element in a list

Tags: sql, list, arraylist, amazon-athena, presto

I need to access to the elements in a column whose type is list according to the other elements' locations in another list-like column. Say, my dataset is like:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY ['hello', 'amazon', 'athena'] AS words,
  ARRAY ['john', 'tom', 'dave'] AS names
)
SELECT * FROM dataset
```

And I'm going to achieve

```
SELECT element_at(words, index(names, 'john')) AS john_word
FROM dataset
```

Is there a way to have a function in Athena like "index"? Or how can I customize one like this? The desired result should be like:

```
| -------- |
| john_word|
| -------- |
| hello    |
| -------- |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_position`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_position):

> `array_position(x, element)` → `bigint`
> Returns the position of the first occurrence of the element in array `x` (or 0 if not found).

Note that in presto array indexes start from 1.

```sql
SELECT element_at(words, array_position(names, 'john')) AS john_word
FROM dataset
```